# How to embed phpinfo() within a page without affecting that page's CSS styles

Tags: css, embed, php

I want to embed `phpinfo()` within an admin page. Keeping the sites navigation and styles. However, the styles applied within the function run amuck with the site's own styles (breaks navigation styles).

Question: How do I keep `phpinfo()` from affecting the page I embed it into?

Comment: you could just iframe it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After digging through the [PHP User Contributed Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) I found most of the solution. I then expanded on what I found and wrapped it up in a function. It strips the `<body></body>` tags, echoes its own customizable styles and then the content of `phpinfo()` inside of `<div id='phpinfo'></div>`.

```
function embedded_phpinfo()
{
    ob_start();
    phpinfo();
    $phpinfo = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $phpinfo = preg_replace('%^.*<body>(.*)</body>.*$%ms', '$1', $phpinfo);
    echo "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #phpinfo {}
            #phpinfo pre {margin: 0; font-family: monospace;}
            #phpinfo a:link {color: #009; text-decoration: none; background-color: #fff;}
            #phpinfo a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
            #phpinfo table {border-collapse: collapse; border: 0; width: 934px; box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #ccc;}
            #phpinfo .center {text-align: center;}
            #phpinfo .center table {margin: 1em auto; text-align: left;}
            #phpinfo .center th {text-align: center !important;}
            #phpinfo td, th {border: 1px solid #666; font-size: 75%; vertical-align: baseline; padding: 4px 5px;}
            #phpinfo h1 {font-size: 150%;}
            #phpinfo h2 {font-size: 125%;}
            #phpinfo .p {text-align: left;}
            #phpinfo .e {background-color: #ccf; width: 300px; font-weight: bold;}
            #phpinfo .h {background-color: #99c; font-weight: bold;}
            #phpinfo .v {background-color: #ddd; max-width: 300px; overflow-x: auto; word-wrap: break-word;}
            #phpinfo .v i {color: #999;}
            #phpinfo img {float: right; border: 0;}
            #phpinfo hr {width: 934px; background-color: #ccc; border: 0; height: 1px;}
        </style>
        <div id='phpinfo'>
            $phpinfo
        </div>
        ";
}
```

Comment: Add arguments by changing to `function embedded_phpinfo(?int $args=null): void` and `phpinfo(args);`

Comment: @theking2 default value for `$args` should be `-1` not `null`. Also, you are missing the `$` in front of `args` when calling `phpinfo`.

Comment: @Stamoulohta: thanks, you are of course right on both instances.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use ob_get_contents() to get phpinfo to an string variable，and phpinfo is still display in page. Then I put ob_get_contents codes in a function and I got the $phpinfo variable.

```
function getPhpinfo()
{
    ob_start();
    phpinfo();
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
    return $data;
}

$phpinfo = getPhpinfo();
var_dump(strlen($phpinfo));
```